# Simpson's rule to estimate distance traveled given velocity at certain points

Tags: calculus, estimation, simpsons-rule

**Problem:**

A boat drives a steady course with a variable speed for 4 hours. The speed is registered at regular intervals in meters per second.

The registration shows $2.4, 4.4, 7.6, 8.4, 8.6, 7.9, 8.3, 8.7, 7.7, 6.5, 7.1, 6.7, 1.4$ *(sorry, but I'm making a point out of this later)*.

Use Simpson's Rule to estimate how far the boat has traveled during the four hours, and its average speed.

Additional question; why can Simpson's Rule be used to estimate the boat's distance traveled?

**My progress:**

There are 13 recordings, which is an odd number, so that should be fine.

Using the Composite Simpson's Rule (with coefficients 1,4,2,4,2...,2,4,1) , I get $$\frac19\left[ 2.4 + 4(4.4) + 2(7.6) + 4(8.4) + \ldots + 4(6.7) + 1.4 \right] \approx 28.09$$ (unless I've made some careless mistake).

Here $\frac19$ comes from $\frac h3$ (from formula) where $h = \frac13$.

Now, as I understand it, this number would - since we're estimating the area under the "curve" (i.e. using Simpson to estimate a definite integral given points) - be a number for the distance traveled.

But since the numbers are given in $\frac ms$, wouldn't this $28.09m$ be an oddly low number? What am I missing here?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your $\frac{1}{9}$ is obtained by $\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{3}$ where one of the $\frac{1}{3}$ is in hours. So instead you should multiply by $3600$, which is the number of seconds in an hour.

Comment: I have no answer to check by, but I end up with around 101km, which makes more sense than 28m.

Answer (score 2):

You did not give the details about how you got the coefficient $\frac 19$,
but you appear to be integrating the speed over the interval $[0,4]$.
That's OK if all your times are measured in hours, but as you noted,
the speeds are all measured in meters per *second*.

Use consistent units throughout the application of Simpson's Rule.
Either convert all the speeds to meters per hour,
or better, convert $4$ hours to $t$ seconds 
and integrate over the interval $[0,t]$.

Comment: Sorry, edited in the part about $\frac19$.

Comment: So $h$ is $\frac13$ hours? Then it is exactly as the answer by KittyL says, and you should use $h = 1200$ (measured in seconds) instead. In any case, what you're doing is equivalent to integration over the interval $[0,12h]$, so if your speeds are meters/second, $12h$ needs to be equal to the number of seconds the boat was motoring, not $4$ seconds.

Answer (score -1):

I have calculated the answer using simpson's one-third rule(the distance travelled by boat in 4 hours) 93.56307km.

Comment: This answer is correct as per simpson's one third rule.